# Where do you ask about where to ask a question?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

My current problem is the following: Win 7 worked fine with 2 monitors. Win 8 will not. (I just installed Win 8 this weekend.)

I searched these places, and I found the path to obfuscation.

- Google, Yahoo, Bing, YouTube
- Code Project
- Stack Overflow
- Super User
- MSDN

I seriously doubt that I'm the first guy who is facing this obstruction.

Is this the place to ask questions about where to ask questions?

Does StackExchange have a place for such questions?

In the meantime, where do I find out how to get Win 8 to recognize my second monitor?

Comment: Did you look at [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: My history on Super User has been very bad, so I purposely avoid the place. Not sure if I'm whining about it or if I'm just doing the right thing and staying away from where I don't belong. Whatever, whatever, in most places on stack exchange my reputation has been slowly increasing (since my first day) but on Super User, for whatever reason, it seems that I just fail, fail, and fail again. Hence, I am apprehensive about further antagonizing that group.

Comment: It really is about reading and following the FAQ of each site. I am not active on Super User, so can't really tell you why you have had that experience.

Comment: @User.1 I'm barely active on Super User but in my experience upvotes are not as easy to come by on SU as they are on SO.  You have to be very clear in what you are looking for, what you have tried, what is actually happening ("doesn't work" doesn't cut it)

Comment: @User.1 Also, I would revisit how you format your questions.  Stop posting 1 sentence per line, it is very hard to read especially when you have more than 2 or 3 sentences.  Instead use paragraphs and complete sentences.  If you need to list a list of steps or bullet points, use the numbered list or bullet formatting.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thank you and plus one for some concrete suggestions. Once you get cooties (which I infer has happened to me on Super User) it's usually a long-term label. I will take your suggestions and add them to others, but I'm not looking forward to the results

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Amazing, I searched 3 different ways to make sure that I wasn't doing exactly that.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this the place to ask questions about where to ask questions?

Yes. See [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec)

> Does StackExchange have a place for such questions?

Yes, it does. It is this very site.

> In the meantime, where do I find out how to get Win 8 to recognize my second monitor?

You can ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 7):

You can ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com). But before you ask add more information to your question than the one line you provided here.

What hardware do you use?
What does *not working* mean?
What did you try?
...

Comment: I'm very apprehensive about Super User, as I have more negative than positive attempts associated with my name there. I tried searching Super User for "two monitors" and "windows 8" and I forget what else; but found nothing. Certainly, I would think, this is a common error that occurs, probably daily. I can't be the first with this.

Comment: @user.1 The best way to improve your rep on Super User is to just *keep at it*. You've still got your site association bonus, so it's not like your reputation has bottomed out. And theoretically, if you ask a good question, it shouldn't matter what your past history looks like.

Comment: @Hannele thanks.  I'm going to hit their meta site first and ask for tips on how to ask the question

Comment: @Hannele Did hours of homework and screen caps, posted, and for the first time, I think, a question of mine on SuperUser did not get flagged, flogged, or forsaken. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your actual question, you read the FAQ for the candidate page you've found and the about page (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/about and https://superuser.com/faq) and determine if it's a proper candidate based on the info you read.

You can find out existing SE sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

If you read an FAQ and are still not sure, in my personal opinion I would post the question as well as concisely post why you think it's a good candidate for the site, as this will show research effort.  Your worst case is it's closed or downvoted, which is okay to happen sometimes as part of onboarding as long as you don't make the same mistakes repeatedly.

But failing that, yes, it's okay to ask this question on meta.